# mysql config variable: where in the world is my.ini?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change one of the mysql variables.

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=2
```

On the external server, I was able to change this in `my.cnf`. However, I cannot for the life of me find this file on my computer. I also cannot find `my.ini` (I am on windows). I can find `my-huge.ini` and various other sizes.

## QUESTIONS

- Might it be called something else?
- Do I have to make it? Or, is there a way to change this option without opening the file?

Since ft_min_word_len already has a value, it must be SOMEWHERE!

I tried

```
mysqld --help
```

but it does not tell me anything really. I  tried:

```
mysqld --help --verbose
```

It says very much and whatever is at the start, I cannot see. It won't let me print to any files: "access is denied"

Edit: I looked for it using

dir /s my.ini

Comment: are you using a WAMP package or did you manually just download mysql as it'll all depend on that.

Comment: It might be in your Windows directory instead of the installation directory. If you use a WAMP package, it might also be in a shared directory. Have you tried searching in the command line using `CD \ ` and `DIR MY.INI /S`?

Comment: I tried "dir /s my.ini"

Comment: I don't remember how I installed it..

Comment: if you've searched the fs and can't find it anywhere then perhaps its not using one and just running internal defaults.  Find the mysql install folder there should be a conf folder under there c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysqlVERSIONNUMBER/ or c:/program files/mysql etc etc

Answer (score 2):

I have a little surprise for you. You said you found `my-huge.ini`. *The folder where `my-huge.ini` resides is the folder `my.ini` should be*. If `my.ini` is not in the same folder, **THEN `my.ini` SIMPLY DOES NOT EXIST**. Consequently, `mysqld.exe` is running on pure defaults for all configuration settings.

Whenever MySQL was installed as a service, there was no `my.ini` created. Over the years, I have noticed that after an MSI installation of MySQL, the file `mysqld.exe` (which is in the bin folder) looks to the parent directory for the `my.ini`.

Let's say you found `my-huge.ini` in `c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysqlVERSIONNUMBER`

Just create the `my.ini` in that place as well. Then, restart the `mysql` service. Open a DOS Window using `Run as Administrator` and run the following:

```
C:\> cd c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlVERSIONNUMBER
C:\> echo "[mysqld]" > my.ini
C:\> echo "ft_min_word_len=2" >> my.ini
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

Give it a Try !!!